# Extjs-Ext.fly() null or not an object

Tags: extjs

hi i have a tabpanel, in which i have two panel but when i try to show a panel using tabpanel.show(). I am getting this message Ext.fly() null or not an object does any one know what the problem is..please help

Comment: Could you please show some code?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the tabpanel or one of its child elements is not rendered. Set your debugger to break on error and have a poke around.